# R sorts a vector on its own accord

Tags: r, sorting, vector

```
df.sorted <- c("binned_walker1_1.grd", "binned_walker1_2.grd", "binned_walker1_3.grd",
    "binned_walker1_4.grd", "binned_walker1_5.grd", "binned_walker1_6.grd",
    "binned_walker2_1.grd", "binned_walker2_2.grd", "binned_walker3_1.grd",
    "binned_walker3_2.grd", "binned_walker3_3.grd", "binned_walker3_4.grd",
    "binned_walker3_5.grd", "binned_walker4_1.grd", "binned_walker4_2.grd",
    "binned_walker4_3.grd", "binned_walker4_4.grd", "binned_walker4_5.grd",
    "binned_walker5_1.grd", "binned_walker5_2.grd", "binned_walker5_3.grd",
    "binned_walker5_4.grd", "binned_walker5_5.grd", "binned_walker5_6.grd",
    "binned_walker6_1.grd", "binned_walker7_1.grd", "binned_walker7_2.grd",
    "binned_walker7_3.grd", "binned_walker7_4.grd", "binned_walker7_5.grd",
    "binned_walker8_1.grd", "binned_walker8_2.grd", "binned_walker9_1.grd",
    "binned_walker9_2.grd", "binned_walker9_3.grd", "binned_walker9_4.grd",
    "binned_walker10_1.grd", "binned_walker10_2.grd", "binned_walker10_3.grd")
```

One would expect that order of this vector would be `1:length(df.sorted)`, but that appears not to be the case. It looks like R internally sorts the vector according to its logic but tries really hard to display it the way it was created (and is seen in the output).

```
order(df.sorted)
 [1] 37 38 39  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
[26] 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Is there a way to "reset" the ordering to `1:length(df.sorted)`? That way, ordering, and the output of the vector would be in sync.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

construct it as an ordered factor:

```
> df.new <- ordered(df.sorted,levels=df.sorted)
> order(df.new)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
```

---

EDIT :

After @DWins comment, I want to add that it is even not nessecary to make it an ordered factor, just a factor is enough if you give the right order of levels :

```
>     df.new2 <- factor(df.sorted,levels=df.sorted)
>     order(df.new)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
```

The difference will be noticeable when you use those factors in a regression analysis, they can be treated differently. The advantage of ordered factors is that they let you use comparison operators as < and >. This makes life sometimes a lot easier.

```
> df.new2[5] < df.new2[10]
[1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(df.new[5], df.new[10]) : < not meaningful for factors

> df.new[5] < df.new[10]
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 15):

Use the `mixedsort` (or) `mixedorder` functions in package gtools:

```
require(gtools)
mixedorder(df.sorted)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
[28] 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
```

Comment: Actually, my df.sorted is the result of gtools::mixedsort. :)

Comment: @Roman: indeed, but the thing is that order will still give you the order according to the normal sort. mixedsort is the mixed equivalent for sort, mixedorder the mixed equivalent for order. Mixedsort doesn't save the order in the object, for that you have to make it an ordered factor.

Comment: @Joris: One does not need to make it an ordered factor and I would advise people against doing so since it will really alter the way the factor gets handled by regression functions in ways that are probably going to be puzzling at first. All one needs is to reorder the levels in a regular factor structure.

Comment: @Dwin : true, I'll update my answer. Keep in mind though that a normal factor does not allow you to test order using the < and > operators.

Comment: Thanks for adding that point about the potential for using comparison operators on ordered factors. Could be handy.

Answer (score 10):

Isn't this simply the same thing you get with all lexicographic shorts (as e.g. `ls` on directories) where `walker10_foo sorts` higher than `walker1_foo`?

The easiest way around, in my book, is to use a consistent number of digits, i.e. I would change to `binned_walker01_1.grd` and so on inserting a 0 for the one-digit counts.

Comment: Sometimes the data "comes at you" rather than being "putty in your hands" from the very beginning. That's why I would never dismiss the value of Greg Warnes mixedsort().

Answer (score 7):

In response to Dwin's comment on Dirk's answer: the data are always putty in your hands.  "This is R. There is no if. Only how." -- Simon Blomberg

You can add `0` like so:

```
df.sorted <- gsub("(walker)([[:digit:]]{1}_)", "\\10\\2", df.sorted)
```

If you needed to add `00`, you do it like this:

```
df.sorted <- gsub("(walker)([[:digit:]]{1}_)", "\\10\\2", df.sorted)
df.sorted <- gsub("(walker)([[:digit:]]{2}_)", "\\10\\2", df.sorted)
```

...and so on.

Comment: Yes, it' all about the how. I'm just an apprentice. Perhaps some day I can make my own light saber. Until then I will use other's.

Comment: @DWin But how will you learn to make your own if you only use others'? ;-)