# order data.frame on non-numerical value

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
320    Dutch  A7     3

321    Dutch  A8     3

322    Dutch  A9     4

323    Dutch A10     1

324    Dutch A11     4

327    Dutch A14     4

325    Dutch A12     3

328    Dutch A15    10

326    Dutch A13     1

329    Dutch A16     3
```

How can I order it so all the `A1, A2, etc.` are in order alphabetically and numerically, so that I get:

```
320    Dutch  A7     3

321    Dutch  A8     3

322    Dutch  A9     4

323    Dutch A10     1

324    Dutch A11     4

325    Dutch A12     3

326    Dutch A13     1

327    Dutch A14     4

328    Dutch A15    10

329    Dutch A16     3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind-of answered your own question. See help for `order` function. And also see [this rant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286299/r-sorts-a-vector-on-its-own-accord-bad-boy).

Comment: You are right, order() can be used - I just thought it was for numbers only. This is what I used:                                                                       Dutch2 <- Dutch[with(Dutch, order(ID)), ]                                                                      assuming that 'Dutch' is the name of the data.frame, and the column used for the order is called 'ID'.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the data frame part for now.  Here's a sample vector that you want to order

```
x <- paste(
  rep.int(LETTERS[1:3], 16),
  rep.int(1:16, 3),
  sep = ""
)
y <- sample(x)
```

Just calling `sort(y)` won't work because number get sorted into lexographical order, so you get something like A1, A10, A11, ...

Instead, use `substring` to split the column into a letter and a number.

```
indexer <- data.frame(
  letter = substring(y, 1, 1),
  number = as.numeric(substring(y, 2))
)
```

Then, as aL3xa suggested, call `order` to order the resulting data frame.

```
o <- with(indexer, order(letter, number))
y[o]
```

To get this to work with a data frame, simply replace `y` with `your_data$index_column`.