# Why R order files as 1 10 100 not 1 2 3?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R sorts a vector on its own accord - bad boy!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286299/r-sorts-a-vector-on-its-own-accord-bad-boy)
>   [How can I read the files in a directory in sorted order using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777367/how-can-i-read-the-files-in-a-directory-in-sorted-order-using-r)

The code given below worked well. However, the problem is that when I typed   dir1 to see the results I found that R order the files as:

```
[1] "data1.flt"   "data10.flt"  "data100.flt" "data101.flt"
[5] "data102.flt" "data103.flt" "data104.flt" "data105.flt"
[9] "data106.flt" "data107.flt" "data108.flt" "data109.flt"
[13] "data11.flt"  "data110.flt" "data111.flt" "data112.flt"
[17] "data113.flt" "data114.flt" "data115.flt" "data116.flt"
.
.
to
.
.
[357] "data91.flt"  "data92.flt"  "data93.flt"  "data94.flt"
[361] "data95.flt"  "data96.flt"  "data97.flt"  "data98.flt"
[365] "data99.flt"
```

which will lead to wrong results.
How to tell R to start reading from 1 to 365 in order(I even used sort(dir1) but didn't sort them).
something like :

```
[1] "data1.flt"   "data2.flt"  "data3.flt" "data4.flt"
```

not like:

```
[1] "data1.flt"   "data10.flt"  "data100.flt" "data101.flt"
```

Here is the code:

```
dir1 <- list.files("C:\\Users", "*.flt", full.names = TRUE)
results <- list()
for (.files in seq_along(dir1)){
    file2 <- readBin(dir2[.files], double(), size = 4, n = w * 67420, signed = TRUE)
    results[[length(results) + 1L]] <- file1[file1 != -9999]*10
}
for (i in seq_along(results)){
    fileName <- sprintf("C:\\New folder (2)\\NewFile%03d.bin", i)
    writeBin(as.integer(results[[i]]), fileName, size = 2)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the structure of the name of your files you could use that instead of grabbing them directly from `dir`.

```
for(i in seq(365)){
    filename <- paste0("data", i, ".flt")
    # Do some stuff with filename
}
```

`paste0` was introduced in R 2.15 so for older versions you'll need:

```
for(i in seq(365)){
    filename <- paste("data", i, ".flt", sep = "")
    # Do some stuff with filename
}
```

---

Further edits because you seem to be confused.  filename gets updated each iteration through the loop.  You can see this by printing the filename each time.

```
for(i in seq(365)){
    filename <- paste("data", i, ".flt", sep = "")
    print(filename)
    # Do some stuff with filename
}
```

Comment: I got error: setwd("C:\\Users\\Amin\\Desktop\\2001")
for(i in seq(365)){
  filename <- paste0("data", i, ".flt")    conne <- file(filename, "rb")
+  file1<- readBin(conne, double(), size=4,  n=360*720, signed=TRUE)
+ file1[file1 != -9999] <- file1[file1 != -9999]*10
+    close(conne)
+  fileName <- sprintf("C:\\Users\\Amin\\Desktop\\New folder (11)\\NewFile%d.bin", b)
+  writeBin(as.integer(file1), fileName, size = 2)}
Error: could not find function "paste0"

Comment: paste0 was introduced in 2.15 - I made an edit to add an alternative for older versions.  But really this is just basic text manipulation to construct the file name.

Comment: But I wonder why the files are still not ordered     setwd("C:\\Users\\Amin\\Desktop\\2001")
 for(i in seq(365)){
 filename <- paste("data", i, ".flt", sep = "")}
 filename
[1] "data365.flt"

Comment: ... The filenames are still sorted.  You're supposed to do something with the filename there.  The loops overwrites 'filename' each time through so you end up with the last one which happens to be data365.flt.  I added another edit to hopefully clarify this...

Answer (score 7):

Because it doesn't interpret the number - it's sorting strings instead

Comment: like pretty much everything else does :)

Comment: It's not broken, nothing to fix!! :) You could change the naming of your files so that the number is padded, i.e. data0001.flt, data0002.flt, data0003.flt - this will fit in with the string sorting rules.

Comment: I renamed the files to which you suggested but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean, it's not working? If you look at the data you posted, that's correctly ordered from data101.flt - what have you done differently?